# Error: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer' in AOS package CSS file

Tags: css, npm, vuejs3, aos.js

I am trying to run my Vue.js project using the npm run serve command, but I am getting an error in the AOS package CSS file. The error message is:

`ERROR in ../node_modules/aos/dist/aos.css

Syntax Error: Error: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\Enzo\node_modules\aos\postcss.config.js
  ...
  `

I have checked the versions of the aos package and the autoprefixer module, and they seem to be compatible. I have also tried deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling all dependencies with npm install, but the error persists.

Could anyone help me understand what could be causing this error and how to solve it? Thank you in advance.